# Transform pandas DataFrames groups - completely, not just a Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, method-chaining

I want to transform each group in a pandas' DataFrame. By group I mean not a single column of the DataFrame, but the entire group. Here is an example of what I mean:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar'],
                   'B' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'two', 'one', 'two'],
                   'C' : [    1,     5,     5,     2,     6,     5],
                   'D' : [  2.0,    5.,    8.,    1.,     2.,   9.]})

def transformation_function(group: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    group = group.copy()
    if all(group.B == 'one'):
        group.D[group.C>2] = group.D[group.C>2] + 1
    else:
        group.A = 'new'
    return group

df.groupby('B').transform(transformation_function)
```

where I would expect

```
     pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'new', 'new', 'foo', 'new'],
                   'B' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'two', 'one', 'two'],
                   'C' : [    1,     5,     5,     2,     5,     5],
                   'D' : [  2.0,    6.,    8.,    1.,    3.,    9.]})
```

as a result. Now, I get the

> AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'B'

which does not make sense to me, because the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) explicitly states

> Call function producing a like-indexed DataFrame on each group and return a DataFrame having the same indexes as the original object filled with the transformed values

I am aware the all examples work Series-based, like `df.groupby('B')['a_column_name'].transform(change_fct)`, but something like that is not possible if one needs all columns for the transformation function.

So, how do I get what I expect, using pandas' method chaining?

Comment: Your expected df is the same as the input df?

Comment: @Allen: They are not the same in my post.

Comment: Interesting! The code to construct your desired output(under the line 'where I would expect') is exactly the same as the code you added to construct your input df.

Comment: @Allen: Do you mean the code `df.groupby('B').transform(transformation_function)`? This throws the mentioned error!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your solution `transform` function working with each column separately, so not possible select columns by names. Need [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
df = df.groupby('B').apply(transformation_function)
    
print (df)
         A    B  C    D
B                      
one 0  foo  one  1  2.0
    1  bar  one  5  6.0
    4  foo  one  6  3.0
two 2  new  two  5  8.0
    3  new  two  2  1.0
    5  new  two  5  9.0
```

How are processing groups is possible see e.g. by `print`:

```
df.groupby('B').transform(lambda x: print (x))
0    foo
1    bar
4    foo
Name: A, dtype: object
0    1
1    5
4    6
Name: C, dtype: int64
0    2.0
1    5.0
4    2.0
Name: D, dtype: float64
     A  C    D
0  foo  1  2.0
1  bar  5  5.0
4  foo  6  2.0
2    foo
3    bar
5    bar
Name: A, dtype: object
2    5
3    2
5    5
Name: C, dtype: int64
2    8.0
3    1.0
5    9.0
Name: D, dtype: float64
     A  C    D
2  foo  5  8.0
3  bar  2  1.0
5  bar  5  9.0
```

---

```
df.groupby('B').apply(lambda x: print (x))

     A    B  C    D
0  foo  one  1  2.0
1  bar  one  5  5.0
4  foo  one  6  2.0
     A    B  C    D
2  foo  two  5  8.0
3  bar  two  2  1.0
5  bar  two  5  9.0
```

Comment: 1. Thanks! What is then the point of the transform function? I might as well write `df.groupby('B')['column_name'].apply(transform_fct_for_series)`, where `transform` is "traditionally" used, right? I mean instead of `df.groupby('B')['column_name'].transform(transform_fct_for_series)`.

Comment: 2. Is the documentation of transform wrong or do I misinterpret it somehow? (How?)

Comment: @Make42 - Hmmm, there should be explained it better. You can check it by `df = df.groupby('B').transform(lamba x: print (x))` - in each loop processing only first columns, then second, ... In another words `groupby.transform` not `'see'` all group like `DataFrame`, but like splitted DataFrame to `Series`